# Problems with sysctl settings somaxconn

Tags: ubuntu, proxmox, sysctl

I'm trying to change the somaxconn settings, but for some reason they are not there.

```
***@***:~# cat /etc/debian_version
bullseye/sid
 
***@***:~# uname -a
Linux *** 5.4.78-2-pve #1 SMP PVE 5.4.78-2 (Thu, 03 Dec 2020 14:26:17 +0100) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
 
***@***:~# sysctl net.core.somaxconn
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn: No such file or directory
```

How can this be?

Comment: Please post the output of the command `virt-what` (install it if is not already installed).

Comment: `root@***:/# virt-what`
`lxc`

Comment: Hmm. You ought to be able to get that sysctl in a container. This may be a problem specific to Proxmox, or to that particular container. Have you tried making a new container?

Comment: In another container, the setting is also missing.

Comment: That makes me think it's something Proxmox is doing. A normal LXC container with network access has this sysctl, as do Docker containers. I don't have much experience with Proxmox, so someone else will probably have to take a look at this.